# PHP json_encode not returning valid json

Tags: php, json

I am running a Debian box with PHP v5.2.17.  I am trying to get around the cross-domain issue with an XML file and am using this got to fetch any xml and return json:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if( strlen($_GET["feed"]) >= 13 ) {
  $xml = file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET["feed"]));
  if($xml) {
    $data = @simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($data);

    echo isset($_GET["callback"]) ? "{$_GET[’callback’]}($json)" : $json;
  }
}
?>
```

The problem is, its not returning valid json to jquery..  The start character is "(" and the end is ")" where jquery wants "[" as the start and "]" as the end.  I've taken the output and used several online validation tools to check it..

Is there a way I can change these characters prior to sending back or pass json_encode options?

Comment: does it work if you remove the `header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` part? I've never had a problem with `json_encode()` and I've never set a header like that either, but perhaps I should be.

Comment: With `(` and `)` You don't actually mean those in `"{$_GET[’callback’]}($json)"`? If yes, just remove them there? Otherwise I would be very suprised to find `json_encode` returning a value with enclosing parenthesis.

Comment: your question title is not true. `json_encode()` does return **valid** JSON, even with SimpleXML objects; the output passes any JSON validator and you can sucessfully `json_decode()` it. The actual problem has already been highlighted by several answer.

Comment: Can you show us your jQuery ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You could change json_encode($data) to json_encode(array($data)) if it expects an array (like you're saying):

```
$json = json_encode(array($data));
```

**EDIT**: Also, I believe the SimpleXml call will result in a bunch of SimpleXmlElements, perhaps json_encode then thinks it should be objects, instead of arrays? Perhaps casting to an array will yield the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You cannot [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)s (that's the type that is returned by [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). You have to convert the data from the XML file into some native PHP type (most likely an array).</del>

**SORRY** that's wrong. `json_encode()` can in fact encode `SimpleXMLElement`s (at least on my PHP version `5.3.4`). So if your client-side code expects an array you must wrap your `$data` in an array:

```
$json = json_encode(array($data));
```

Comment: I don't understand why an array created by iterator_to_array() also needs to be converted to array in order to be a valid array for json_encode

Answer (score 0):

We can use json_encode() function most probably on array. so you first take XML content into PHP array and then apply json_encode().I think this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending an empty callback parameter or something, but the callback parameter in jQuery must look exactly like this: `callback=?`